# Can I avoid a Scan Operation when trying to retrieve all items in a specific date range in dynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table which contains one unique partition key `id` and a bunch of other attributes including a `date` attribute.

I now want to get all records in a specific time range however as far as I understood, the only way to do this is to use a scan.

I tried to use a GSI on `date` but then I can not use `BETWEEN` in the `KeyConditionExpression`.

Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

Q: Are you providing one-and-only-one `Partition Key` value?

A: If `YES`, then you can `query`.  If `NO`, it's a `scan`.

You are currently in scan territory, because you need to search over multiple `id`s.

To get to the promised land of queries, consider DynamoDB's [design pattern for time series data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html).  One implementation would be to add a GSI with a compound `Primary Key` representing the date. Split the date between a `PK` and `SK`.  Your `PK` could be `YYYY-MM`, for instance, depending on your query patterns.  The `SK` would get the leftover bits of the date (e.g. `DD`).  Covering a date range would mean executing one or several queries on the GSI.

This pattern has many variants.  If scale is a challenge and you are mostly querying a known subset of recent days, for instance, you could consider replicating records to a separate reporting table configured with the above keys and a TTL field to expire old records.  As always, the set of "good" DynamoDB solutions is determined by your [query patterns and scale](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach).